# Computation of a Fourier transform of a tempered distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

If $x$ is a Schwartz function and $\theta$ is a tempered distribution given by $$\theta(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{it}x(t)dt.$$
What is the Fourier transform of $\theta$?

I know $\mathcal{F}\theta(x)=\theta\mathcal{F}(x)$ and
$$\theta\mathcal{F}(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{it}dt\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-i\langle t,s\rangle}x(s)ds.$$

But I am unsure of what to do from here. Can anyone help?

Comment: $\theta$ is a tempered distribution with a direct Schwartz function dual i.e. $$\theta'(t) = e^{it}\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\left(t-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$ From here, you either recognize that the FT of a rectangle is a sinc and translate the sinc to be centered at $1$, or you calculate the FT by hand.

Comment: Yes but I don’t know how to calculate it by hand which is why I asked